# Problemas ao imprimir FastReport

Tags: delphi, impressão, fast-reports

Estou com problema ao imprimir relatórios com FastReport no Delphi 2010.
Ao imprimir na impressora a primeira vez, imprime corretamente, mas na segunda vez que tento imprimir o relatório não imprime corretamente.

Não utilizo dataset no relatório. Nos demais relatórios do sistema acontece o mesmo problema ao imprimir.

Talvez seja o problema da impressora. Modelo: HP Officejet J3680 All-in-One.

Segue o relatório (fr3):
https://goo.gl/jfqVfq

"frxReport1" está com as configurações Padrões:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
frxReport1.LoadFromFile(arquivoRel);

if pImp then begin
  frxReport1.PrepareReport();
  frxReport1.Print;
end else
  frxReport1.ShowReport;
```

Como deveria imprimir (Primeira vez está certo):
[image]

Como está imprimindo na segunda vez: 
[image]

Comment: Consegue disponibilizar o arquivo que você está carregando no seu frxReport1 ?

Comment: Coloquei ali como está e como deveria ficar para ajudar. Não utilizo dataset, é somente um campo texto, mas colocarei o código aqui sim.

Comment: Cara, teu código funciona perfeitamente aqui. Para facilitar a sua vida. Baixe o doPDF, e coloque-o como impressora padrão. e verifica se o problema continua.

Comment: E ai @cava, deu certo ?

Comment: Desculpa a demora @VictorTadashi estava de férias, mas enfim, instalei o programa que você mencionou e infelizmente funcionou normalmente, utilizarei esta opção antes de imprimir direto na impressora. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não consegui resolver meu problema de imprimir diretamente na impressora, na minha opinião deve ser algum problema na impressora, mas não sei dizer ao certo, pois não possuo outro PC ou impressora para testar.

Minhas configurações: Windows 8.1, Delphi 2010 e impressora HP.

Utilizarei o doPDF para resolver meu problema conforme comentário do amigo Victor.